# Not sure if JQuery validate is working correctly on email address reg expressions

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate, email-validation

I set a rule for my email address field like so

```
$('#Email').rules("add", {
    required: true,
    email: true
});
```

but when I type in 'something@gmail.c' (using just 1 or 2 characters after the period) it shows it as valid (good). Is this a correct email extension reg ex or is something wrong here? It even validates to true with 'something@g' and then a tab is pressed!!!

here are some pics

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are thousands of top level domains, more than .com .gov .net etc. It's not possible to verify all of them, so it just accepts anything after the period. For example, .na is the country code top level domain for Namibia

Comment: it's also validating as true if I enter something@g and pres tab. I'll post a pic!

Comment: [**jQuery Validate v1.12.0 changelog‌​**: *"Methods: Update email to use HTML5 regex, remove email2 method"*](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/releases/tag/1.12.0)